# Swap body tags between two HTML files

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have two separate HTML files (index.html and home.html) and a javascript (bodyswapscript.js) file.  I'm trying to figure out how to swap the body of home.html (only) into the body of the index.html by using java script.  Basically replacing body tags between HTML files.

I have posted my html code and java script below.  The html is quick and dirty, so I'm only interested in swapping out the body information from index.html with home.html

1.) index.html

```
<head>
        <meta name="generator" content=
              "HTML Tidy for Windows (vers 14 February 2006), see www.w3.org">
        <meta charset="utf-8">

        <title> My Profile</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css">    
</head>

<header>
    <hgroup>
        <center><h1>Index</h1>
        <h4>index page</h4></center>
    </hgroup>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bodyswapscript.js"></script>


<nav>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="header">
            <ul>
                <li><a id="homeContainer" href="home.html">Home</a></li>
                <!-- <li><a id="testContainer" href='test.html'>test</a></li>
                <li><a id="pageContainer" href="page.html">page</a></li> -->
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

</nav>

</header>
<body>
    <article>

  <div id='swapcontent'>
  index page
  </div> 

</article>
    </body>
<footer>
    <p>&copy; copy right, all rights reserved.</p>
</footer>
```

2.) home.html

```
<header>
    <hgroup>
        <center><h1>home.html</h1>
        <h4>text</h4></center>
    </hgroup>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>

</header>
<body>
    <article>

        <div id='swapcontent'>
            This is my home page
        </div> 

    </article>
</body>
```

3.) bodyswapscript.js

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $( 'li>a[id$="Container"]' ).click(function(event) 
    {
        event.preventDefault();
        var href = $(this).attr('href');
        alert("Loading " + href);
        $('#swapcontent').load(href);
        return false;
    });
});
```

4.) Supporting CSS

```
 * {
    font-family: Lucida Sans, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

body {
    width: 720px;
    margin: 0px auto;
}

header h1 {
    font-size: 36px; 
    margin: 0px;
}

header h2 {
    font-size: 18px; 
    margin: 0px; 
    color: #888;
    font-style: italic;
}

nav ul {
    list-style: none; 
    padding: 0px; 
    display: block;
    clear: right; 
    background-color: #2B60DE;
    padding-left: 4px; 
    height: 24px;
}

nav ul li {
    display: inline; 
    padding: 0px 20px 5px 10px;
    height: 24px; 
    border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
}

nav ul li a {
    color: #EFD3D3; 
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 13px; 
    font-weight: bold;
}

nav ul li a:hover {
    color: #fff;
}

article > header time {
    font-size: 14px; 
    display: block; 
    width: 26px;
    padding: 2px; 
    text-align: center; 
    background-color: #993333;
    color: #fff; 
    font-weight: bold; 
    -moz-border-radius: 6px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 6px; 
    border-radius: 6px; 
    float: left;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

article > header time span {
    font-size: 10px; 
    font-weight: normal;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

article > header h1 {
    font-size: 20px; 
    float: left;
    margin-left: 14px; 
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 5px #333;
}

article > header h1 a {
    color: #993333;
}

article > section header h1 {
    font-size: 16px;
}

article p {
    clear: both;
}

footer p {
    text-align: center; 
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #888; 
    margin-top: 24px;
}
```

This code was pulled from the following URL: http://jsfiddle.net/Christophe/hj9ry/1/

Comment: `html` at Question is invalid. `<header>` element is not same as `<head>` element. `<header>` and `<footer>` elements should be child nodes of `<body>` element

Comment: Not related to your problem, but sorry to be the bearer of bad news, `hgroup` is dead: http://html5doctor.com/the-hgroup-element/

Comment: Why is `html` loaded in `#swapcontent` if requirement is to "swap" `<body>` elements? Are you trying to replace entire content of `<body>` at `index.html` with `html` content of `<body>` at `home.html`?

Comment: Yes,  I'm trying to replace entire content of <body> at index.html with html content of <body> at home.html

Comment: @linos _"Yes, I'm trying to replace entire content of <body> at index.html with html content of <body> at home.html"_ Correct invalid `html`, then you can use a wrapper element at home.html, fragment identifier at `.load()`, `.unwrap()`; see Answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct invalid `html`, include wrapper parent element for content of `<body>` at `home.html`; call `.load()` with fragment identifier referencing wrapper element within `home.html`; use `.unwrap()` to remove wrapper element at `index.html` at `complete` function of `.load()`

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="generator" content="HTML Tidy for Windows (vers 14 February 2006), see www.w3.org">
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <title> My Profile</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css">
</head>


<body>
  <header>
    <hgroup>
      <center>
        <h1>Index</h1>
        <h4>index page</h4></center>
    </hgroup>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bodyswapscript.js"></script>


    <nav>
      <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="header">
          <ul>
            <li><a id="homeContainer" href="home.html">Home</a></li>
            <!-- <li><a id="testContainer" href='test.html'>test</a></li>
                <li><a id="pageContainer" href="page.html">page</a></li> -->
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>

    </nav>

  </header>
  <article>

    <div id='swapcontent'>
      index page
    </div>

  </article>
  <footer>
    <p>&copy; copy right, all rights reserved.</p>
  </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

home.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
  <div id="body">
  <header>
    <hgroup>
        <center><h1>home.html</h1>
        <h4>text</h4></center>
    </hgroup>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>

</header>
    <article>

        <div id='swapcontent'>
            This is my home page
        </div> 

    </article>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

bodyswapscript.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('li>a[id$="Container"]').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var href = $(this).attr('href');
    // alert("Loading " + href);
    $('body').load(href + " #body", function() {
      $("#body *:first").unwrap()
    });
    return false;
  });
});
```

plnkr http://plnkr.co/edit/r8WTsQ9Xm3ZLsRp8nwLr?p=preview

Comment: Thank You very much.  
One last question, How difficult would it be to retain the header and footer content when swapping the body content?

Comment: @linos It would not be that difficult, though that is not present Question _"Yes, I'm trying to replace entire content of <body> at index.html with html content of <body> at home.html"_ ? You could use same approach, that is, wrap the content to be loaded from home.html within an element, load only than element into corresponding element at index.html.

Comment: Thanks Again.  I'm a newbie at this, so I'm treading lightly in the deep waters.  Should I ask another question, or can I continue it here?  I would like to  wrap the content to be loaded from home.html within an element, load only that element into corresponding element at index.html.  Also, I would like to be able to click the back back one page button to go back to previous page.  I hope I did not confuse the question.

Comment: _"I would like to wrap the content to be loaded from home.html within an element, load only that element into corresponding element at index.html. Also, I would like to be able to click the back back one page button to go back to previous page. I hope I did not confuse the question."_ To avoid confusion would ask separate Question, including specific requirements within text of actual Question; with link to present Question, describing new requirements, above, which present Question did not include. See also http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . Does Answer resolve current Question?

Answer (score 0):

You can use IFrames in html to show your contents of index.html in homw.html

Or 
You can use 
 in your home file